# Vagrant / laravel/homestead / HeidiSQL casual problems

Tags: laravel, ssh, vagrant, homestead, heidisql

LM:

```
Vagrant 1.8.1
Laravel Homestead version 3.0.1
```

Problems:

> 1. [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to ...
> 2. [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could ...
>      refused it.
> 3. Refuse to connect to DB via Heidi

I've browsed many discussions and found some solutions for you. Feel free to post similar problems.

Comment: can you connect via ssh?

Comment: Yes I was able to, there was opened only one port for mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure what PHP are you using and check `php.ini` for `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`
- Check your `homestead.rb` and set ports for guest and host, same as in the `my.cnf` accesed by `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf` inside the box!
- Check your `database.php` [(mine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrZhY.png) leave default, you can add
  `'port' => env('DB_PORT', 33060),` You need to change only `.env` file in your **root project** [(mine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hnMB.png)
- There was also problems with need to change localhost/127.0.0.1 depending on the route.
- Run `vagrant reload` & `vagrant provisions`
- My Heidi setup [sql][3] [ssh][4] (links in comment → no rep)

I hope that this will help somebody, because I was quite mad!